# PIL unable to open image via absolute path of image - IOError [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, sorl-thumbnail

I'm trying to open an image created via [sorl thubmnail](http://sorl-thumbnail.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) using PIL.

Here is a part of the code

```
print user.image
print user.image.url
print user.get_images(size='500')
print user.get_images(size='500').url
```

This outputs

```
images/users/DSC_0889.JPG
/media/images/users/DSC_0889.JPG
<sorl.thumbnail.images.ImageFile object at 0x11288df10>
/media/cache/f9/ed/f9ed5e89154c42a2aff758b193618b12.jpg
```

Using PIL to open it results in the following results

**Attempt 1:**

```
im = Image.open(user.image)
```

This works fine.

**Attempt 2:**

```
im = Image.open(user.get_images(size='500'))
```

This gives the error

```
TypeError at /scripts/user/crop-image/
read() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Traceback:
File "/Users/jaskaran/Desktop/coding/buyingiq/buyingiq/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  112.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/jaskaran/Desktop/coding/buyingiq/buyingiq/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  22.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/jaskaran/Desktop/coding/buyingiq/buyingiq/views/www/user.py" in crop_image
  114.         im = Image.open(user.get_images(size='500'))
File "/Users/jaskaran/Desktop/coding/buyingiq/buyingiq/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py" in open
  2097.     prefix = fp.read(16)
```

**Attempt 3:**

```
 im = Image.open(user.get_images(size='500').url)
```

This gives the error

```
IOError at /scripts/user/crop-image/
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/media/cache/f9/ed/f9ed5e89154c42a2aff758b193618b12.jpg'
```

If I point my browser to `127.0.0.1:8000/media/cache/f9/ed/f9ed5e89154c42a2aff758b193618b12.jpg` the image is opened, so the image exists.

How can I use PIL to open this image?

Comment: You need to use `.name`. `user.image.name`.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Using `user.get_images(size='500').name` gave this error `IOError at /scripts/user/crop-image/
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'cache/fb/37/fb37faba63b618df7ee0394d04222d93.jpg'`

Comment: You should use the path to the file; not the url. Possibly with `os.path.join(os.path.abspath(__file__), user.get_images(size='500').url)`

Comment: @klasske I tried that, it gave the same error `IOError at /scripts/user/crop-image/
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/media/cache/fb/37/fb37faba63b618df7ee0394d04222d93.jpg'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `media` folder was outside my main project directory.

Accessing it like `settings.MEDIA_ROOT + str(user.get_images(size='500').name)` solved the issue.